How can I remove **just** the x button (keeping the maximize and minimize buttons) from a tkinter window?
I have this but it removes all buttons. It does allow alt-tabbing unlike overideredirent(True) though:
    hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(self.root.winfo_id())
    style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongA(hwnd, -16)  # GWL_STYLE
    WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000
    WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000
    WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000
    new_style = style | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    new_style = new_style & ~WS_SYSMENU
    windll.user32.SetWindowLongA(hwnd, -16, new_style)
    self.root.update_idletasks()

Any ideas?

Per this answer, there's no direct way to remove the close button by itself, but you can override the protocol handler for WM_DELETE_WINDOW to simply do nothing when the close button is clicked. Here's a quick working example:
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', 'break')  # tell the Close button to do nothing
# optional quit button
btn_close = tk.Button(root, command=root.quit, text='Quit')
btn_close.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()

I've included a 'Quit' button just so you're not stuck with the window, but you get the idea.
That said, while this works it also violates the POLA because the close button isn't technically disabled. It still looks the same and is still interactable - it just doesn't do anything anymore.

"there's no direct way to disable the close button" - yes, there is (see my other comment). You just can't remove the button, without also removing the minimize/maximize buttons as well.

@RemyLebeau Fair point, I'll make an edit

WS_MINIMIZEBOX and WS_MAXIMIZEBOX require WS_SYSMENU.
You cannot remove the X button by itself, but you can disable it, by using GetSystemMenu() and either EnableMenuItem() or DeleteMenu(), eg:
GWL_STYLE = -16
WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000
WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000
WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000
SC_CLOSE = 0xF060
MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000
MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001
MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002

hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(self.root.winfo_id())
style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
new_style = style | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU
windll.user32.SetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, new_style)

menu = windll.user32.GetSystemMenu(hwnd, false);
# either this ...
windll.user32.EnableMenuItem(menu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
# or this ...
windll.user32.DeleteMenu(menu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

self.root.update_idletasks()

The other option is to owner-draw the titlebar yourself, then you can draw it however you want, but you will still have to handle/ignore the default commands.

Note there's UB: [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer).
